# Opening links inside the tabs with JS Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a basic tab pane with 5 panes like this

```
<li><a href="#Formais" data-toggle="tab">Formais</a></li>
```

using twitter bootstrap and in everyone of their pane contents I have various links that I would like to open inside the content

Im very new to JS, bootstrap and have no idea how to do this.
( the only idea I had was to use some kind of include when the link is clicked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery (and ajax) was the way to go..
On the link:

```
<a onclick="callUrl('urlpath')" href="#">link</a>
```

and a div inside the pane

```
<div id="divid"></div>
```

and finally:

```
function callUrl (URL) {
  $('#divid').load(URL);
}
```

This helped me solve the problem of opening a link to a outside source inside the pane.
Maybe I was not so clear on the question, I apologize.